# Send a email with Attachment in R using Gmail

Tags: r, email, gmail-api

I am trying to attach a file from my system to send it to an email id using R. I am using the **gmailr** package to send the mails. I have tried the following code for the same.

```
library(gmailr)

mime() %>%
to("abcd@gmail.com") %>%
from("xyz@gmail.com") %>%
text_body("My First Email using R.") -> first_part

first_part %>%
subject("Test Mail from R") %>%
attach_file("BazaarQueriesforURLData.txt") -> file_attachment

send_message(file_attachment)
```

I have been able to send text based messages but I am unable to send attachments from R. My attachment in the default directory folder only.I have seen many solutions on internet but I am unable to find a solution.

I would like to have a solution that has proper OAuth or Json based authentication as Google blocked my attempt to use smtp based authentication.

Comment: Do you have any possibility to get an error message? Can you show how the message looks before trying to send it?

Comment: @Tholle I get a bounce message saying there was a error sending your mail. But when I look at my send items the attachment is there but it is not send to the user and instead I get a bounce message in my inbox saying "There was a error sending your mail". It is working fine with attachment.

Comment: I am unable to replicate this error with gmailr, package version 0.7.1.9000 - are you still having issues with this?

Comment: @Stedy - I have not tried it for long. Will check and let you know.

Comment: @KshitijMarwah are you generating an application specific code for this Gmail account? I have found that I need to generate a specific password on Gmail for these kinds of scenarios. Does this account have two-step authentication enabled?

Comment: @MatthewCrews - Its only 1 step authentication.I am not sure of the specific password you are talking about. Can you tell me how to go about creating passwords for this.

Comment: @KshitijMarwah Here is what you need: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tool in development:

```
# install.packages("devtools")

library(devtools)
install_github("gmailR", "trinker")
```

*if you use Windows, you'll need to use Rtools and devtools to install

Answer (score 0):

other tools are packages mailR 
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mailR/mailR.pdf

and sendmailR

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sendmailR/sendmailR.pdf

Here is a blog post tutorial

http://blog.yhat.com/posts/building-email-reports-with-r.html